# How Do I Use a Selected Item In A List Box As A Name For an new generated text file

Tags: c#, text, selected

How Do I Use a Selected Item In A List Box As A Name For an new generated text file? (visual c#)

here's the piece of code:

```
string path = @"C:\\Public Key Pin\Test.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("The first line!");
    }
}
else if (File.Exists(path))
{
    MessageBox.Show("File with this path already exists.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Your question and code don't make much sense. First of all, you are recreating the file with File.Create and File.CreateText two times. Second, what UI framework are you using? WinForms, WPF? And third, where do you want to use that value?

Comment: Thanks, you've actually helped me with another problem i was having because i didn't realize it was creating the text file twice. It was giving me an error saying that another process was using the newly created file and it was giving me an error, so thank you.

Comment: title doesn't need any tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume your listbox ID is `ListBox1`

in asp.net
then try

```
string path = "C:\\Public Key Pin\"+ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text+".txt
```

in Winforms
try this

```
string path = "C:\\Public Key Pin\"+ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.SelectedItem)+".txt
```

Comment: gald it helped you.. do upvote and mark as answer if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ListBox ls = new ListBox();
string path = @"C:\\Public Key Pin\" + ls.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt";
```

And override the ToString() method in the class this is selected.